# How to manage page object from the other user control

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a problem. I want to create a toolbar.xaml user control. I open a page in content of TabItem In mainpage.xaml. How can access and manage this page from the toolbar user control. 
Please help. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

either user `static` variables in parent control and call them directly in the child one.

or raise `EventHandlers` from child control and subscribe them in parent control.